# Bulk Users in AD

Tags: powershell, scripting, active-directory, windows-server-2008, server

I'm trying to create bulk users using PowerShell using this script below but I'm getting an error stated below. please help!

The script:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Import-Csv "C:\Scripts\bulkadusers.csv" | ForEach-Object {
 $userPrincinpal = $_."samAccountName" + "@sigusa.net"
New-ADUser -Name $_.Name `
 -Path $_."ParentOU" `
 -SamAccountName  $_."samAccountName" `
 -UserPrincipalName  $userPrincinpal `
 -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString "1234" -AsPlainText -Force) `
 -ChangePasswordAtLogon $false  `
 -Enabled $true
Add-ADGroupMember "Domain Admins" $_."samAccountName";
}
```

Error:

> New-ADUser : Directory object not found
>   At C:\scripts\bulkADusers.ps1:4 char:11
>   + New-ADUser <<<<  -Name $*.Name 
>   + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (CN=Johnsontest,...C=sigusa,DC=net:String) [New-ADUser], ADIdentityNotFoundException
>
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Directory object not found, Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.NewADUser
>
>   Add-ADGroupMember : Cannot find an object with identity: 'j.test' under: 'DC=sigusa,DC=net'.
>   At C:\scripts\bulkADusers.ps1:11 char:18
>
>   + Add-ADGroupMember <<<<  "Domain Admins" $*."samAccountName";
>   + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (j.test:ADPrincipal) [Add-ADGroupMember], ADIdentityNotFoundException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SetADGroupMember.ValidateMembersParameter,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.
>      AddADGroupMember

Answer (score 0):

You used `$.` it's `$_`.

Untested fixed code:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory 
Import-Csv "C:\Scripts\bulkadusers.csv" | ForEach-Object { $userPrincinpal = $_."samAccountName" + "@sigusa.net" 
New-ADUser -Name $_.Name  -Path $_."ParentOU" -SamAccountName $_."samAccountName"  -UserPrincipalName  $userPrincinpal -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString "1234" -AsPlainText -Force) -ChangePasswordAtLogon $false -Enabled $true 
Add-ADGroupMember "Domain Admins" $_."samAccountName"; }
```

Comment: ok that worked but now its giving me a new error

New-ADUser : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Add-ADGroupMember'.
At C:\scripts\bulkADusers.ps1:3 char:1
+ New-ADUser -Name $_.Name  -Path $_."ParentOU" -SamAccountName $_."samAccountName ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-ADUser], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.NewADUser

Comment: Yes, `Add-ADGroupMember` needs to be on a new line, fixed in the answer

Answer (score 0):

I did this using a CSV file with the data, then within Excel used concatenate to put together the string to create each user with a specific delimiter that I used with a `For /F` command to read the input.txt passed to the `dsadd user` command.  I'm posting this as a workaround if powershell isn't available due to restrictions for example.